# How do I uninstall minikube on a Mac?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, uninstallation, apple-silicon

I have a Mac with Apple Silicon (M1) and I have minikube installed. The installation was done following https://medium.com/@seohee.sophie.kwon/how-to-run-a-minikube-on-apple-silicon-m1-8373c248d669  by executing:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-darwin-arm64
sudo install minikube-darwin-arm64 /usr/local/bin/minikube
```

How do I remove minikube?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried to follow any online material to delete Minikube?? Test if this works for you and let me know if you face any issues.

Try using the below command :

```
minikube stop; minikube delete &&
docker stop $(docker ps -aq) &&
rm -rf ~/.kube ~/.minikube &&
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/localkube /usr/local/bin/minikube &&
launchctl stop '*kubelet*.mount' &&
launchctl stop localkube.service &&
launchctl disable localkube.service &&
sudo rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/ &&
docker system prune -af --volumes
```

Reference used: [Delete minikube on Mac](https://gist.github.com/rahulkumar-aws/65e6fbe16cc71012cef997957a1530a3)

Comment: This works. I saw this reference before I posted but it was not clear to me if I can trust it

Comment: Just watch out for: `docker system prune -af --volumes`, because it **clears ALL your docker volumes**. Not only kube related.

Comment: also watch out for `rm -rf ~/.kube` because that will clear out all of your k8s contexts, not just Minikube

Comment: On mac the command ```launchctl disable localkube.service &&``` is giving me the following error: ```Unrecognized target specifier. <service-target> takes a form of <domain-target>/<service-id>.
Please refer to `man launchctl` for explanation of the <domain-target> specifiers.
Usage: launchctl disable <service-target>```

Comment: have you ran the command one by one?

Answer (score 4):

```
    minikube stop; minikube delete
    docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
    rm -r ~/.kube ~/.minikube
    sudo rm /usr/local/bin/localkube /usr/local/bin/minikube
    systemctl stop '*kubelet*.mount'
    sudo rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/
    docker system prune -af --volumes
```

Comment: This command can delete a lot more than just minikube.