# Minikube doesn't start on Mac OS Ventura 13.4 (IF_VBOX_NOT_VISIBLE error)

Tags: virtualbox, minikube, macos-ventura

The problem I'm going to describe is dealt with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277019/how-to-fix-vm-issue-with-minikube-start), but sadly none of proposed solutions worked for me.
After a long period (and maybe after several OS updates) I returned to Minikube but it doesn't start, returning the following error log:

```
Exiting due to IF_VBOX_NOT_VISIBLE: Failed to start host: driver start: Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue
  Suggestion: Reboot to complete VirtualBox installation, verify that VirtualBox is not blocked by your system, and/or use another hypervisor
```

As suggested I executed

```
minikube delete
```

then I removed my local version of VirtualBox and installed version 7.0, rebooting my Ventura 13.4 and executing both following instructions:

```
minikube start
minikube start --driver=virtualbox
```

The problem persists in both cases, even after authorizing **com.oracle** in Settings->Privacy and security->Complete access to disk (in the general page of Settings->Privacy and security there's no mention to **com.oracle** and I simply activated option *App Store and Identified developers*.
Here are some details about my Minikube version:

```
minikube version: v1.24.0
```

I even tried to remore and reinstall MiniKube to have a recent version, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73600518/how-do-i-uninstall-minikube-on-a-mac)
I hope some of you have any hint to fix the problem, if further information is needed don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, after much struggling.
It seems that starting from Mac OS 13, VirtualBox driver is no longer supported by Minikube.
A possible solution (that worked for me) is using Docker driver.
First of all, it is necessary to install Docker and start it, then the following command should work:

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

I hope this will work for people with same problem.

Greetings.